# CDF on unit square

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> A point $(a,b) \in [0,1]^2$ is selected at random. Let $X: [0,1]^2 \to [0,2]$ be the random variable that maps every point to the sum of its components, i.e. $X(a,b) = a + b$. Find the CDF $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(a + b \leq x)$ by considering the cases $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $1 < x \leq 2$ and $2 < x$ separately. What is the corresponding PDF?

My approach was to figure out the subsets $\{a + b \leq x\}$ of the unit square that satisfy the respective inequalities and then calculate the corresponding area of that subset. If we divide this area by the area of the unit square we should get $\mathbb{P}(a + b \leq x)$.

For example for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ we have that for fixed $a \in [0,1] : b \in [0, x-a]$ and thus the subset should consist of every point under and on the curve $b_x(a) = 1 - a$ from $0$ to $1$, that is $\int_{0}^{1} (1 - a) da$. This integral evaluates to $1/2$, which intuitively makes sense to me, but I'm not at all sure about the formalism. Is this the correct way to approach this problem? What about the other cases? Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $a+b\le x$ where $0 \le x \le 1$ the region is a triangle with base and height $x$ which has the area $x^2/2.$ To use an integral as you did, the limits on $a$ should be from $0$ to $x$ rather than $0$ to $1$ as you have it.

When $1 \le x \le 2$ a good way is to subtract the area of the triangle *above* the line $a+b=x$ from $1.$

Comment: Thanks, coffeemath! If I understand you correctly, then in the second case the area is just $1-\frac{x^2}{2}$?

Comment: The second area is $1-(2-x)^2/2.$ If you draw it in the case where $1 \le x \le 2,$ the part jutting out beyond the square has length $x-1,$ and this has to be subtracted from $1$ to get the sidelength of the upper triangle, which is thus $1-(x-1)=2-x.$

Comment: Oh, I get it know. I didn't think of drawing it like that. Very nice! Thanks.